# RichTextBox can't recognize line properly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox, rtf

I tried to find similar problem but no luck.

I need to read RTF line by line, modify it and save. 
It's 4am, I'm out of ideas and it's driving me nuts...

**PROBLEM:**

Element I want to read is in Lines[10], I can see it clearly during runtime, in local vars. But RichTextBox continue to see it in Lines [11] while Lines[10] remains empty for it.

**IDEA:**

I think that might be caused by poorly formatted RTF, here is how this line looks like ("!" is necessary part of this string, this is how code recognizes lines it needs to take care of):

```
"\f!LOREMIPSUM=NW"
```

**My code:**

To not mess up RTF syntax here is method I use:

```
   public string ReadLine(int line)
    {
        int s1 = RTxtBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line);
        int s2 = line < RTxtBox.Lines.Length - 1 ?
                  RTxtBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line + 1) - 1 :
                  RTxtBox.Text.Length;

        RTxtBox.Select(s1, s2 - s1);
        yPos = line;
        xPos = s1;
        return RTxtBox.SelectedText;

    }
```

**MCV Sample RTF for tests:** (Line[1] is causing poblem)

```
    {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1250\deff0\deflang1045\deflangfe1045\deftab648{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset238{\*\fname Arial;}Arial CE;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 MS Serif;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green0\blue0;}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\nowidctlpar\ri-504\tqr\tx9864\cf1\lang1033\f0\fs20 !LOREMIPSUM\cf0\f1\fs24\par
\page\cf2\f0\fs20 !LOREMIPSUM=NW\cf0\f1\fs24\par
\cf1\b\f0\fs28 LOREMIPSUM\cf0\b0\f1\fs24\par
\pard\nowidctlpar\ri-504\tx1512\tx5184\tx6336\tqr\tx9864\cf2\f0\fs20 !LOREM\cf0\f1\fs24\par
\cf2\f0\fs20 !DOLOR=VW\cf0\f1\fs24\par
\pard\nowidctlpar\ri-504\tqr\tx9864\cf2\lang1045\f0\fs20 !SITAMET\cf0\f1\fs24\par
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: You can easily get an off-by-one bug if the RTB contains a long line that needs to be wrapped.  Set the rtb's WordWrap property to False and try again.

Comment: @dbc - It's winforms,
HansPassant - unfortunately but this is not an issue - it's already set to false

Comment: Your RTF has a "\page" break in there.  The RTF control doesn't know what to do with that.